# Lower bounds from Fourier dimension?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

According to Mattila, *Geometry of sets and measures in Euclidean spaces*, p. 168, the **Fourier dimension** $\text{dim}_F(A)$ of $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is the unique number in $[0,n]$ such that for any $0<s<\text{dim}_F A$ there exists a non-zero Radon measure $\mu$ with spt $\mu\subset A$ and $|\hat\mu(x)|\le |x|^{-s/2}$ for $x\in\mathbb R^n$, and that for $\text{dim}_F(A)<s\le n$ no such measure exists.

Does this condition on $\mu$ for $\text{dim}_F(A)>0$ imply a nontrivial lower bound on the $\mu$-measure of a ball of radius $r$, $\mu(B(x,r))$ in terms of $r$, for $\mu$-almost all $x$? For instance, a lower bound like $r^s$ for a constant $s$?

(The reason for asking being that positive Hausdorff dimension is enough to get such an *upper* bound and I'm wondering if one can get *lower* bounds by strengthening the assumption "positive Hausdorff dimension" to "positive Fourier dimension" or something similar.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fourier dimension doesn't directly say anything about lower bounds for the mass of balls. Fourier dimension is smaller or equal than Hausdorff dimension, and in order to give a bound of the form $\mu(B(x,r))\ge r^s$, the exponent $s$ needs to be large.

This suggests that one should seek a notion of dimension that gives *larger* values than Hausdorff dimension. In fact, what you need here is exactly *packing* dimension.

If $\mu$ is a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, let us define its (upper) packing dimension as
$$
\dim_P\mu = \inf\{ \dim_P A: \mu(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus A)=0\},
$$
where $\dim_P(A)$ is the packing dimension of $A$: for the definition, see for example Chapter 2 in

**Falconer, Kenneth**. Techniques in fractal geometry. *John Wiley & Sons, Ltd.*, Chichester, 1997

There is an alternative characterization of packing dimensions of measures in terms of mass decay (see Proposition 10.3 in Falconer's book):
$$
\dim_P\mu = \inf \left\{s: x:\limsup_{r\to 0} \frac{\log\mu(B(x,r))}{\log r}\le s \text{ for $\mu$-a.e. } x \right\}
$$

In particular, if $s>\dim_P\mu$, then for $\mu$ almost all $x$ it holds that $\mu(B(x,r)) \ge r^s$ for all small enough $r$ (depending on $x$).

Hausdorff and packing dimensions (of sets and measures) coincide often for "natural" fractals, but not always.

Note, finally, that if $s>n$, then for *any* Radon measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ one has $\mu(B(x,r)) \ge r^s$ for all sufficiently small $r$ (depending on $x$). This follows from the above comments (since packing dimension of a measure can't exceed $n$: take $A=\mathbb{R}^n$ in the definition), but it can also be proved directly with the help of standard covering lemmas.

Comment: I guess what I really want for the Fourier dimension question is more like $\mu(B(x,r))\ge r^s$ for all $x$, not just $\mu$-almost every $x$, but then that doesn't exactly make sense either...

Comment: You can ask for $\mu(B(x,r))\ge r^s$ for all $x$ in the support of $\mu$, there are certainly many measures satisfying this for some $s$, but I still don't see any relation to Fourier dimension.

Comment: It is known that $\limsup \mu(B_r)/r^s$ is relatively well behaved and one has analogs of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, but I thought the OP was asking the much more difficult question about the behavior of $\liminf\ldots$.